# Oracle Http server ISNT-07551

Tags: oracle, apache, weblogic14c

I'm try to install OHS, but there's an error: INST-07551: Not all dependent featuresets for install type "Collocated HTTP Server (Managed through WebLogic server)" could be found. The following prerequisites were found t
o be missing:
wls_server - 12.2.1.4.0em_fmc - 12.2.1.4.0

My version of weblogic is 14.1.1 and I install the plugisng for this version (mod_wl_24.so, libdms2.so and libonssys.so)

I install the plugisng for this version (mod_wl_24.so, libdms2.so and libonssys.so)